# Does there exist a metric under which $\mathbb{R}$ is incomplete?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Does there exist a metric under which $\mathbb{R}$ is incomplete?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152243/real-numbers-equipped-with-the-metric-d-x-y-arctanx-arctany-i

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the metric to induce the usual topology on $\mathbb R$, otherwise the question becomes silly. So, you are essentially looking for a homeomorphic space to $\mathbb R$ which is metrizable and incomplete. Just notice that $\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ with the standard topology.