# Is $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ Cauchy sequence with the metric $d(x,y)=|\arctan x−\arctan y|$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

> Let $(\Bbb{R},d)$ be a metric space where $d(x,y)=\left\vert\arctan x−\arctan y\right\vert$. Is the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ a Cauchy sequence with this metric?

The definition of [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) is that, for any given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that $|x_m-x_n|<\varepsilon$ whenever $m>n\ge n-0$.

For this sequence we get 
$$x_m-x_n = \arctan \frac1m - \arctan \frac1n.$$
But how can the above expression be simplified or estimated?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152243/real-numbers-equipped-with-the-metric-d-x-y-arctanx-arctany-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)
=\arctan(\frac{x-y}{1+xy})
$,
$\arctan(\frac1{n})-\arctan(\frac1{m})
=\arctan(\frac{\frac1{n}-\frac1{m}}{1+\frac1{n}\frac1{m}})
=\arctan(\frac{m-n}{mn+1})
$.

Therefore, if
$N < n < m$,
since
$\frac{m-n}{mn+1}
<\frac{m}{mN}
=\frac1{N}
$,
$\arctan(\frac1{n})-\arctan(\frac1{m})
<\arctan(\frac1{N})
<\frac1{N}
$
so the sequence *is* Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider a bijection $(-\pi/2,\ \pi/2)$ to $\Bbb R$ which preserves the metric and check whether the image of this sequence is Cauchy or not.

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange theorem, if $x\ne y$ $$\arctan x-\arctan y=\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}(x-y)$$ for some $\xi\in (x,y)\cup(y,x)$.

Therefore, $d(x,y)\le \lvert x-y\rvert$. Which means that \begin{align}id_{\Bbb R}: (\Bbb R,\lvert\bullet\rvert)&\to (\Bbb R,d)\\x&\mapsto x\end{align}
is a Lipschitz-continuous map. Since Lipschitz-continuous maps are uniformly continuous, and uniformly continuous maps send Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences, $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\ge 1}$ must be Cauchy in $(\Bbb R,d)$.