# sequentially compact $d(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the metric $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ $d(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$.
>
> Show that $\mathbb{R}$ is not sequentially compact with respect to that metric.

I know that it s bounded by $d(x,y)<\pi$.

But it should not be closed. But having trouble coming up with sequences that will converge but not in the metric space.

Also know that $x, y$ are unbounded so somehow the image will not be?

Would it be easier to use open covers, so for an arbitrary open cover there is no finite cover?

Comment: the anwer might be here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152243/real-numbers-equipped-with-the-metric-d-x-y-arctanx-arctany-i but still confused

Comment: Let $T1$and $T2$ be topological spaces.
Let $f:T1→T2$ be a continuous mapping.
If $T1$ is compact then so is $f(T1).$ But not sure if $d(x,y)$ is continous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to that metric.  But there is nothing in that space to which any of its subsequences could converge.

(To see that this is a Cauchy sequence, remember that $\arctan x\to\pi/2$ as $x\to\infty.$)