# Show that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is not complete , where $d(x,y) =|\arctan(x) - \arctan(y)|$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let us define a metric $d$ on the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ as $d(x,y) =|\arctan(x) - \arctan(y)|$. It is routine that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is a metric space. I also claim that it not a complete metric space. Let's consider the following sequence

$$(x_n) = (1,2,3,...).$$

The sequence is a Cauchy sequence, but it is not a convergent sequence. I want to prove this claim formally.

Can you help me to write the proof formally?

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking (hence it's in a comment not an answer) - but another possible approach would be to show that $\arctan : (\mathbb{R}, d) \to ([-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}], d_e)$ is an isometric embedding (where $d_e$ is the Euclidean metric restricted to $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$) but its image is not closed.

Comment: **Abridged proof.** Just observe $\arctan(x) \to \pi/2.$ Q.E.D.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real numbers equipped with the metric $ d (x,y) = | \arctan(x) - \arctan(y)| $ is an incomplete metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152243/real-numbers-equipped-with-the-metric-d-x-y-arctanx-arctany-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's see that $(x_n)$ is indeed Cauchy. It is known that $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\arctan(t)=\pi/2$, therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan(n)=\pi/2$. Now let $\varepsilon>0$ and by the definition of the limit, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $|\arctan(n)-\pi/2|<\varepsilon/2$. Suppose that $n,m$ are integers greater than $n_0$. Then we have $d(x_n,x_m)=|\arctan(n)-\arctan(m)|\leq|\arctan(n)-\pi/2|+|\pi/2-\arctan(m)|<\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon$. But the sequence $(x_n)$ does not converge at any point in $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, if $(x_n)$ converged to $x$ then we would have that $d(x_n,x)\to0$, i.e. $|\arctan(n)-\arctan(x)|\to0$. but we already know that $|\arctan(n)-\pi/2|\to0$, and by uniqueness of the limit it should be $\arctan(x)=\pi/2$. But no such $x$ exists on the real line.

Comment: Hello, sorry for posting this so late. I'm reading this post and I'm thinking of how to prove that by adding $\pm\infty$, $([-\infty,\infty], d)$ will be a complete metric? How can I choose the Cauchy sequence and prove it rigorously? I know by intuition that $\arctan(\pm\infty)=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$. Thank you.

Comment: @Mike Hello. The idea is the following: the only problem point is about sequences "tending to infinity". You do not have to "choose" a Cauchy sequence because you are not trying to find a problematic one, you have to prove that ALL Cauchy sequences are actually convergent. Take an arbitrary Cauchy seq. $(x_n)$ and distinguish two cases: if it is bounded, i.e. $|x_n|\leq M$ for all n and then prove it is convergent. If it is unbounded, you can actually prove that it converges to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Can you add more details if possible, perhaps in the post? I can understand why we should split into two cases, but I'm not sure how to write in details. Thank you.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I think every Cauchy sequence is bounded, so I am not sure what you means by unboundedness

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Every Cauchy sequence in the usual metric is bounded, yes. I mean a sequence that is Cauchy with respect to the arctan metric but is unbounded in the usual absolute value metric.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn ah!! you are right... I got confused... Would you mind providing a detailed proof? I am really interested in this question but I am not sure how to prove it