# If two metric spaces are topologically equivalent (homeomorphic) imply that they are complete?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

My definition of topologically equivalent is: *every convergent sequence in $(X, d_A)$ converges at $(X, d_B)$ to the same limit and vice versa.*

I know that

Let $(X,d_A)$ and $(X, d_B)$ be two strongly equivalent metric spaces, if $(X, d_A)$ is complete then $(X, d_B)$ is complete.

I was thinking that if these spaces were just topologically equivalent yet would the statement be true?

My answer is no.

But I can't think of a counter example.

Comment: I think there is missing   a part :definition is *every convergent sequence in $(X, d_A)$ converges at $(X, d_B)$ to the same limit - and **vice versa***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $(\Bbb R,d)$ , where $d$ is the  usual metric and $(\Bbb R,\rho)$ , where $\rho$ is the  metric defined by $$\rho(x,y)=\vert \arctan x-\arctan y \vert$$ Then $(\Bbb R,d)$ is topologically equivalent to $(\Bbb R,\rho)$(How ?), but one is complete while the other is not (How?)

Try to fill the gaps!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152243/real-numbers-equipped-with-the-metric-d-x-y-arctanx-arctany-i for the proof of non-completeness

Answer (score 5):

$(-1,1)$ is topologically equivalent to $\mathbb  R$ via the homeomorphism $x \to \frac x {1-|x|}$. $(-1,1)$ is not complete but  $\mathbb  R$  is complete. [Usual metric on both spaces].