# Example of a metric $d^*$ for $R^2$ that is equivalent to the Euclidean metric $d$ and which is such that $(R^2, d^*)$ is totally bounded

Tags: general-topology

Example of a metric $d^*$ for $\mathbb{R^2}$ that is equivalent to the Euclidean metric $d$ and which is such that $(\mathbb{R^2}, d^*)$ is totally bounded.

My guess is uniform metric space for $\mathbb{R^2}$ where metric $d^*=\min\{1,d\}$. Uniform metric is equivalent to Euclidean mtric, but I don't know whether uniform metric space is totally bounded or not, and it seems to be not.

Comment: You’re right in thinking that the truncation metric is not totally bounded. I would start by finding a totally bounded metric on $\Bbb R$ that is equivalent to the usual metric.

Comment: Take a function (e.g. the stereographic projection's inverse) $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to S^2-N$. If you define $d_f(x,y)=d_{\mathbb{R}^3}(f(x),f(y))$, what do you get?

Comment: @Caffeine Thanks, but I don't understand how the new metric constructs.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I can't figure out such a metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Cathy: Here’s a hint: find a homeomorphism between $\Bbb R$ and some open interval $(a,b)$, and use it to define such a metric; there are nice homeomorphisms with the intervals $(-1,1)$ and $\left(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right)$. Equivalently, find an incomplete metric on $\Bbb R$ that is equivalent to the usual one. Give it a bit of thought first, but if you can’t think of one, look at the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789177/is-there-any-metric-on-r-with-which-it-is-incomplete).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you so much! I got it.

Comment: @Cathy: Excellent! You’re very welcome.